# Hellgate: London Client Closes on Start-up Because of an Error

Tags: hellgate-london

I downloaded the T3Fun client for Hellgate: London Global. I installed as usual, but when I launched the client, it gives me this error:

[image: Hellgate: London error.]

**How do I fix this so I can play Hellgate: London?**

I'm running on a Windows 8 machine with more than adequate hardware power. I tried running on compatibility mode for Windows 7 and Windows Vista to no avail. I also have the program run as administrator but the issue persists.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is the error message not in english or any language for that matter?

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I was thinking maybe I didn't have the right language packs installed, but the game *is* in English, so it makes me wonder myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs because I launched the game during **server maintenance** (I wasn't aware at the time). I launched it again after the maintenance period and the game booted up fine.

Comment: @Gauzy, I can't accept it until 12 hours later. I'll accept it when the time comes. :)